# Can't get osfigures working with opensans font

Tags: fonts

I can't get

`\usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=0.95]{opensans}`

to work, or the even simpler

`\usepackage[default,osfigures]{opensans}`

Both give me this error `! LaTeX Error: Unknown option`osfigures' for package `opensans'.` This has been happening for several years, so I've gone without the Old-style Figures, but it's now bothering me. It's even happening on a brand new LaTeX install (specifically MacTeX basic2019 plus added 'opensans' package), and even after I try re-installing the 'opensans' package. It works just fine if I remove the 'osfigures' option. What am I missing?

(This is the opposite problem of [Using Open Sans font with LaTeX: Alphabetic chars right, numeric chars wrong](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137482/using-open-sans-font-with-latex-alphabetic-chars-right-numeric-chars-wrong).)

Comment: the package doesn't know this option. Why do you think it should? And what should it do?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it actually is a package option, it's in the manual and it works on my system. Not sure why it doesn't work for the OP though.

Comment: @Marijn not in the current version. But I found it in texlive2018.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that explains a lot :) CTAN seems to be down so I wasn't sure about different versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `osfigures` (old style figures) option is used in previous versions of the `opensans` package. In the most recent version this option is called `oldstyle`.

Compare two versions of the manual:

*Version 1.1*

> **3.2.3 Figure selection**
>
> Open Sans provides two different figures versions (see table 1):
>
> - *Lining figures* are designed to match the uppercase letters in size and color; they are used by default.
> - *Text figures* (also known as *old-style figures*) are designed to match the lowercase letters.
>
> To use text figures by default when calling `\fosfamily`, enable the `osfigures` package option:
>
> `\usepackage[osfigures]{opensans}`
>
> To use Open Sans as default font with text figures:
>
> `\usepackage[default,osfigures]{opensans}`

*Version 2.2*

> **3.2.4 Figure versions**
>
> Open Sans provides two figure styles (see table 2):
>
> - *Lining figures*, designed to match the uppercase letters in size and color
> - *Old style figures* (also known as text figures), designed to match lowercase letters
>
> The opensans package uses lining figures by default (`lining` option). To select old style figures, use the `oldstyle` option. 
>   Two figure widths are also available:
>
> - *Tabular figures*, which each have the same width
> - *Proportional figures*, which vary in width according to their shape
>
> The opensans package uses tabular figures by default (`tabular` option). To select proportional figures, use the `proportional` option. Notice that tabular oldstyle figures are not available; when requesting such a combination, proportional old style figures are provided as a fallback.

Comment: Many thanks, @Marijn. Not sure how I was managing to read an old version of the manual. But CTAN not responding at the time probably didn't help.